# Finding palindromes in c, variable(s) messes up

Tags: c, while-loop, palindrome

I am assigned to do a program, which searches from input file palindrome and if it finds, it is written to output file. I have to use for both buffers with dynamic memory allocation, and arrangements with the text should be done in functions. Word is amount of symbols separated by space.
Between words there may be more spaces, they should be ignored.

Problem of this program for me is that the program doesn't work as "x" value gets messed up (and maybe "y").

```
while (i[(*x)] && i[(*x)]==' ')
```

As i've noticed this line(^) changes "x" value not as it should

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

#define MAX 255

int check_if_palindrome(char *i, int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= y)
        return 0;
    while (x < y)
        if (tolower(i[x++]) != tolower(i[--y]))
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
void searching_for_word(char *i, int *x, int *y)
{
    while (i[(*x)] && i[(*x)]==' ')
        (*x)++;
    (*y) = (*x);
    while (i[(*y)]!=' ')
        (*y)++;
}

int main()
{
    char *reading;
    char reading_file[MAX];
    char *writing;
    char writing_file[MAX];
    int x, y, i, j;
    FILE *read;
    FILE *write;
    puts("File name for input :");
    scanf("%s", reading_file);
    puts("File name for output :");
    scanf("%s", writing_file);
    read=fopen(reading_file, "r"); 
    if(read==NULL)
        perror("File does not exist");
    write=fopen(writing_file, "w");
    if(write==NULL)
        perror("File cannot be created");
    else{
        reading=malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
        writing=malloc(MAX*sizeof(char));
        while(fgets(reading, MAX, read)!=NULL) 
        {
            x=0;
            do{
                searching_for_word(reading, &x, &y);
                if(check_if_palindrome(reading, x, y)==1){
                    j=0;
                    for(i=x; i<y; i++){
                    writing[j]=reading[i];
                    j++;
                    }
                    writing[j]='\n';
                    printf("%d\n", j);
                    for(i=0;i<=j;i++)
                    fputc(writing[i], write);
                }
                x=y;
            }
            while (reading[x]);
        }
    }
    fclose(read);
    fclose(write);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (i[(*x)] && i[(*x)]==' ')` can be replaced with `while (i[(*x)]==' ')`

Comment: @CoolGuy it still does the same.

Comment: The test should be on the second `while`: `while (i[(*y)] && i[(*y)] !=' ') (*y)++;`. That way, you have `y == x` when there sre no more words (in addition to `i[x] == '\0'`).

Comment: Some minor points: You really don't need the `writing` buffer; you can do the output from the input string, because it is never modified by your word-finding and palindrome functions. You could also create `reading` on the stack, as you do for the filenames. (But if you `malloc`, you must also `free`.) Your `else` in `main` only catches the case that the output file can't be opened. The main loop will still execute when you can't open the input file. It's maybe better to call `exit(1)` after `perror.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your word-searching function is basically okay, but there are two points: You scan beyond the buffer, because the null terminator isn't a space. And you don't catch white-space characters other than space, which will not catch the new-line character the `fgets` leaves at the end of the line.

The solution is to test for `'\0'` when you advance `y` and to use `isspace` from `<ctype.h>`:

```
void searching_for_word(const char *i, int *x, int *y)
{
    while (isspace(i[*x])) (*x)++;
    *y = *x;
    while (i[*y] && !isspace(i[*y])) (*y)++;
}
```

(I've made `i` a `const char *`, because you don't change the string. You can also go easy on the parentheses. You need them only to clarify that you increment the pointed-to value rather than the pointer itself.)

Comment: Thanks for giving and explaining to me these solutions.